# Flipping youtr character sprite backwards in sfml c++

Tags: c++, window, sfml, sprite

I am having some small issues getting my sprite character to flip around. Basically I have a character that can walk to the right.. I am looking to flip it so that it looks like it is walking left.  I haven't found a working solution at the moment so any help would be amazaing!

I am using:

SFML 2.1
C++

I have tried:

```
  guy.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(guy.getGlobalBounds().width, 0, guy.getGlobalBounds.width * -1, guy.getGlobalBounds.height));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way of doing it is to scale it with +/- 1 factors as follow:

```
sf::Sprite sprite(texture);
sprite.setOrigin({ sprite.getLocalBounds().width, 0 });
sprite.setScale({ -1, 1 });
```